# 8 ball hitting another ball in a game of pool

Tags: pool

if I call my pocket for an 8 ball shot. I shoot my 8ball toward the pocket. its going toward the pocket but hits another ball that's on the table and still goes in do you lose the game.  not a combo shot to make the 8ball  it just hits it on the way

Comment: As far as I can see, you've already asked this question once. If you think that one *isn't* a duplicate, please comment on your first question rather than making a new post. Thanks!